# Extract a word from a string based on the character index

Tags: ruby, string

I have two strings:

- `"What the hell is T3GARY and U81J9H"`
- `"What the hell is T3GARY"`

I need to extract the word `"T3GARY"` from these strings.

I already have the index of `"T"`. I defined a method:

```
def next_space(string, index)
  # TODO: Case index reach -1 (end of line)
  until string[index] == " " do
    index += 1
  end
  index
end
```

I can get the result as `string[index..next_space_index]`. This works with the first string, but not with the second, due to it not having any space at the end of line.

How can I make it work?

Comment: what word are you extracting? there might be an easier solution

Comment: the "T3GARY", this code is different each time refresh. So what I have is the index of "T".

Comment: You mean you want to search for `T3GARY` everytime? Or the first word that starts with `T`?

Comment: The word that start with T, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the first word that starts with a capital T:

```
"What the hell is T3GARY and U81J9H"[/T\w+/]
# => "T3GARY"
```

If you want all those words comprised of just upper-case letters and numbers:

```
"What the hell is T3GARY and U81J9H".scan(/\b[A-Z0-9]+\b/)
# => => ["T3GARY", "U81J9H"]
```

Comment: Why no word boundaries in the first example?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 The data didn't need it because T started the word. In the second case without that it picked up on the capital W.